# In a Solana program create a wallet to hold SOL that the program can use to accept SOL and pay it out

Tags: javascript, rust, solana

I have a program on the Solana blockchain which works fine, however I now want to integrate a function for the program to receive SOL hold it in an account and then send it out to users as needed.
From the docs it seems I need to use a PDA with a seed phrase and bump.
This is what I have created so far.

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::AccountsClose;

declare_id!("Cq1TSA1obVQZzw2YYxvFN6Q5ia5TYxSbwyZQ9JwQCbBL");


#[program]
pub mod myepicproject {
    use anchor_lang::solana_program::{program::invoke, system_instruction::transfer};

    use super::*;
    pub fn start_stuff_off(ctx: Context<StartStuffOff>) -> ProgramResult {
        // get a referance to the account 
        let base_account = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;
        // initliase total_count. 
        base_account.total_pools = 0;
        Ok(())
    }
    // old name which I don't want to change as used in other places function is add_pool 
    pub fn add_gif(ctx: Context<AddGif>, image_link: String, pool_name: String, pool_desc: String, win_opt:String, close: u32, verify:String, fee:u8) -> ProgramResult {
        let base_account = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;
        let wins: Vec<String> = win_opt.split(';').map(|s| s.trim().to_string()).collect(); //chars().filter(|c| !c.is_whitespace()).collect()
        // make a program address which will hold the SOL for this pool 
        let pool_wallet = &ctx.accounts.pool_wallet;
        let pool = PoolStruct{
            pool_wallet: pool_wallet.to_account_info().key.to_string(),
            pool_id: base_account.total_pools,
            image_link: image_link.to_string(),
            user_address: *base_account.to_account_info().key,
            pool_name: pool_name.to_string(), 
            pool_balance: 0,
            pool_description: pool_desc.to_string(),
            win_options: wins, 
            close_date_time: close, 
            verify_url:verify.to_string(),
            owner_fee: fee,
            result: "".to_string(), 
            closed: false, 
            entries: Vec::new()
        };
        base_account.pool_list.push(pool);
        base_account.total_pools += 1;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn add_result(ctx: Context<AddGif>,result:String, pool_id:u32 ) -> ProgramResult{
        //TODO: Make this only callable by the pool owner. 
        let base_account = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;
        let mut i = 0; 
        let mut found = false;
        for p in &base_account.pool_list {
            if p.pool_id == pool_id {
                found = true;
                break;
            } 
            i += 1;
        }
        if found {
            base_account.pool_list[i].closed = true;
            base_account.pool_list[i].result = result.to_string();
        };
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn place_bet(ctx: Context<AddGif>, pred: String, pool_id:u32, stake_bal:u32, user:String) -> ProgramResult {
        let base_account = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;
        let pool_wallet = &mut ctx.accounts.pool_wallet;
        // TODO: check prediction is one of possible options 
        // TODO: Add payment to this function 
        // TODO: make sure today is before the close date. 
        let bet = EntryStruct{
            user: user,
            prediction: pred,
            stake_bal: stake_bal
        };
        let mut i = 0;
        let mut found = false;
        for p in &base_account.pool_list{
            if p.pool_id == pool_id {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            i += 1;
        };
        if found{
            let sb = stake_bal as u64;
            let account_lamports = **pool_wallet.to_account_info().lamports.borrow();
            let transfer_amount = sb.checked_sub(account_lamports).ok_or(0)?;

            if transfer_amount > 0 {
                invoke( 
                    &transfer(
                        ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info().key,
                        pool_wallet.to_account_info().key,
                        transfer_amount,
                ),
                &[
                    ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
                    pool_wallet.to_account_info(),
                    ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info()
                ],    
            )?;
            }
            base_account.pool_list[i].pool_balance += stake_bal as u64;
            base_account.pool_list[i].entries.push(bet);
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct StartStuffOff<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space= 10240)]
    pub base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(pool_name: String, item_name: String, bounty: u64)]
pub struct AddGif<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>,
    #[account(init, seeds=[pool_name.as_bytes(),b"pool_wallet"], space=9000, bump = 5, payer=user)]
    pub pool_wallet: Account<'info, PoolWallet>,
    // #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}



#[derive(Debug, Clone, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct PoolStruct{
    pub pool_wallet: String,
    pub pool_id: u32,
    pub image_link: String,
    pub user_address: Pubkey,
    pub pool_name: String, 
    pub pool_balance: u64, 
    pub pool_description: String,
    pub win_options: Vec<String>,
    pub close_date_time: u32, 
    pub verify_url: String, 
    pub owner_fee: u8,
    // TODO: to allow for pools with more then 1 winning result perhaps result should be an array?
    pub result: String,
    pub closed: bool,
    pub entries: Vec<EntryStruct>
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct EntryStruct{
    pub user: String,
    pub prediction: String,
    pub stake_bal: u32,
}

//Tell solana we want to store on this account 
#[account]
pub struct BaseAccount {
    pub total_pools: u32,
    pub pool_list: Vec<PoolStruct>,
}

#[account]
pub struct PoolWallet{
    pub balance: u64 
}
```

I have also created the following JS tests.

```
const anchor = require('@project-serum/anchor');

const { SystemProgram, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } = anchor.web3;

const main = async() => {
  console.log(" Starting test...");
  
  const provider = anchor.Provider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  const program = anchor.workspace.Myepicproject;

  const baseAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  

  const tx = await program.rpc.startStuffOff({
    accounts: {
      baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
      user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId
    },
    signers: [baseAccount],
  });

  console.log("Your transaction signiture", tx);

  let account = await program.account.baseAccount.fetch(baseAccount.publicKey);
  console.log(' Total Pools', account.totalPools.toString())

  //call add_gif
  const poolWallet = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  await program.rpc.addGif("insert image linke here", "Test Pool","This is a test Pool", "option 1; option 2", 9897, "Verify here", 5,{
    
    accounts: {
      baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
      poolWallet: poolWallet.publicKey,
      user:provider.wallet.publicKey,
      systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId
    },
    signers: [baseAccount],
  });
  await program.rpc.addGif("insert image linke here 3", "Test Pool 2","This is a test Pool 2", "2option 1; 2option 2", 789897, "2Verify here", 2,{
    accounts: {
      baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
    }
  });
  await program.rpc.addResult("winner 1",0,{
    accounts: {
      baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
    }
  });
  await program.rpc.placeBet("winner 1",1,125,"user",  {
    accounts: {
      baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
    }
  })

  account = await program.account.baseAccount.fetch(baseAccount.publicKey);
  console.log("Total Pools count ", account.totalPools.toString())

  console.log("Pool list: ", account.poolList)

};

const runMain = async () => {
  try{
    await main();
    process.exit(0);
  }catch (error){
    console.error(error);
  }
};

runMain();
```

The tests fail with an error.

`Translating error Error: unknown signer:`

This issue is I don't know if I am making the errors in the Rust program code, or if that is fine and my test code is at fault.
Is anyone able to confirm is the program code makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `signer` tag, like: `#[account(signer)]` above `base_account`

Comment: Cool that moves us a step forward but I get the this error now. ```Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account ```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the correct public keys for your signers. In your test script, make sure `baseAccount.publicKey`, `poolWallet.publicKey`, and `provider.wallet.publicKey` are set to the correct keypair public keys.

Verify that you're adding the signers correctly. In your test script, use the signers field in the `rpc` function to include the signers. For example, when calling `program.rpc.addGif` or `program.rpc.addResult`, make sure to provide the correct signers.

For example:

```
await program.rpc.addGif("insert image linke here", "Test Pool", "This is a test Pool", "option 1; option 2", 9897, "Verify here", 5, {
  accounts: {
    baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
    poolWallet: poolWallet.publicKey,
    user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
    systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
  },
  signers: [baseAccount, poolWallet],
});
```